# alternative to window.find jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there an alternative to find a text in a `div` except

```
window.find(text)
```

This command opens the search dialog box in firefox which I would like to avoid.

My aim is to highlight certain words inside a div when searching.

Comment: Were you looking for a way to intercept the normal control+f to give it a different behavior?

Comment: JQuery normally defaults to pulling things from the document rather than the window, so your code provided might be unconvensional. You could see if there is a document.find? maybe that has the desired behavior with the most minimal rework.

Comment: What is it you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I want to highlight certain words inside a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery Highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html), sample usage :

```
$(document).highlight("word");
```

or

```
$(".div_class").hightlight("word");
```

This will create a DOM element (`span`) around the word with the class `hightlight` then just add the relevant CSS to highlight the word, something like

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF88;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$('div[text == "mysearch"]')

you could then extend that to add a highlight css class over it if you wanted.